# How can I fix a bogus date error in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to update a folder and I get the following message in TortoiseSVN:

> Error at entry 2 in entries file for
>   PathToFile: Bogus Date

Is there a way I can fix this through TortoiseSVN?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried deleting the folder and recommitting it?

Comment: What I ended up down was just checking out the project again.  Not ideal but none of the other SVN commands would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and cleanup didn't work either. Here's what I did to resolve it

- Checkout to new folder
- Export all items from corrupt folder
- Copy over clean checkout

#### Checkout To Clean Folder

Use TortoiseSVN's standard checkout commands to checkout to a *different* folder.

#### Export all items from corrupt folder

From Explorer, Right-click on the corrupt folder and drag to the desktop. Select "Export all items here". This basically copies the entire folder except for the .svn meta folders.

#### Copy over clean checkout

Copy the exported items over the newly checked out version. This restores any changes you might have made and puts you in a place to check them in.

Comment: I hate to do this every now and then. Versioning program should make programmers life easier not harder. I wonder if mercury and/or git have the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but I just came up against it, considering the time for a checkout runs around 2 hours, deleting and doing a complete new CO wasn't an option. I did however checkout the directory with  the problem to a new folder, then in the file system deleted the corrupt folder and copied the newly checked out one into it. Seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try svn clean up followed by a update and then try committing it. For some reason your entries file is corrupt.